# Simple square root calculator

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

Very simple square root calculator. I am sure it's terrible and can be made much better.

I feel it's way too many lines.

```
import random

## ask user for a number to find sq root for
num1 = input("Please enter number for which we'll find sq root:\n")

## generate a random number and test it
randomNum1 = random.randint(1,9)
print("Random number is " + str(randomNum1))

ranMul1 = 0

while True:
  if float(ranMul1) == float(num1):
    print("square root of " + str(num1) + " is " + str(randomNum1))
    break
  else:
    randomNum1 = round((float(randomNum1) + (float(num1)/float(randomNum1))) / 2, 4)
    ranMul1 = round(randomNum1 * randomNum1,4)
    print("Trying number " + str(randomNum1))
    continue
```

Comment: Search for "Newton's method for square roots".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the community :). A few pointers:

1. The code does not follow [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You should follow the `snake_case` naming convention for variables.
2. Split code into separate functions.
3. Instead of the code running as is, the execution condition should be placed inside an [`if __name__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) block.
4. If you're on python 3.6+, make use of f-strings over concatenating separate variables and casting them to strings over and over.
5. Cast the input from user as float as soon as it is read.
6. I don't think you need to round the random variable calculated to 4 digits. For print purpose, you can use the precision specifier.
7. Again, if using python 3.6+, you can also provide type hinting.

---

The above mentioned points, and a few more changes, your code would be:

```
from math import isclose
from random import randint


def calculate_sq_root(num: float) -> float:
    "generate a random number and manipulate it until we calculate square root of input number"
    random_num = randint(1, 9)
    print(f"Random number is {random_num}.")
    while not isclose(num, random_num * random_num):
        random_num = (random_num ** 2 + num) / (random_num * 2)
        print(f"Trying number {random_num:.4f}")
    return random_num


def get_input() -> float:
    "ask user for a number to find sq root for"
    return float(input("Please enter number for which we'll find sq root:\n"))


def main():
    user_num = get_input()
    sq_root = calculate_sq_root(user_num)
    print(f"Square root of {user_num} is {sq_root}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your docstring for `calculate_sq_root` should use triple-quotes, not quotes.

Comment: Also, the cast to `float` is redundant here: `float(num / random_num)` - Python will do type promotion.

Comment: @Reinderien yes. those points are mentioned in pep 8. I edited the code in tio.run page itself, so not much formatting could be done.

Answer (score 12):

The great input from @hjpotter92 gets you 99% of the way there. The only additional comment I have is about this:

```
while num != random_num * random_num:
```

Exact comparison of floating-point numbers is problematic. You're going to want to pick some (very small) number, usually called epsilon, below which the error is insignificant and call that "close enough".

Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose for more details.

Comment: updated this in my reply too. thanks